# NullPointerException out of nowhere

Tags: android, user-interface, bluetooth, nullpointerexception

So my code has been working fine, and I was added some extra functionality to the GUI, and now all of the sudden I'm getting a null pointer exception. I can't figure out what I could have changed to make this happen. I have dumbed down the code to where the error is.

```
public class AndroidBluetooth extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static BluetoothAdapter myBtAdapter;
private static BluetoothDevice myBtDevice;
private ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> btDevicesFound = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
private Button btnScanDevice;
private TextView stateBluetooth;
private ListView listDevicesFound;
private InputStream iStream;
private OutputStream oStream;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
private String newDeviceAddress;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;

private static TextView mTitle;

// Name of the connected device
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;

/**
 * Set to true to add debugging code and logging.
 */
public static final boolean DEBUG = true;

/**
 * Set to true to log each character received from the remote process to the
 * android log, which makes it easier to debug some kinds of problems with
 * emulating escape sequences and control codes.
 */
public static final boolean LOG_CHARACTERS_FLAG = DEBUG && false;

/**
 * Set to true to log unknown escape sequences.
 */
public static final boolean LOG_UNKNOWN_ESCAPE_SEQUENCES = DEBUG && false;

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;


// Member fields
//private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
//private final Handler mHandler;
//private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
//private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
//private int mState;

//private EmulatorView mEmulatorView;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

//public boolean customTitleSupported;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE );
    // Set up window View
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    stateBluetooth = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.titleTvRight );
    startBluetooth();
    myBtAdapter = null;
    CheckBlueToothState();

    //customTitleBar( getText( R.string.app_name).toString(), getText( R.string.app_name).toString() );
}
/**
public void customTitleBar( String left, String right ) {
    if( right.length() > 20 ) right = right.substring( 0, 20 );

    if( customTitleSupported ) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customlayoutbar );
        TextView titleTvLeft = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.titleTvLeft );
        TextView titleTvRight = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.titleTvRight );

        titleTvLeft.setText( left );
        titleTvRight.setText( right );

    }
}
*/
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.option_menu, menu );
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
    case R.id.connect:
        startActivityForResult( new Intent( this, DeviceList.class ), REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE  );
        return true;
    case R.id.preferences:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected( item );
    }
}

private void CheckBlueToothState() {
    Log.i("HUH", "0");
    if( myBtAdapter == null ) {
        Log.i("HUH", "1");
        stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT supported" );
    } else {
        Log.i("HUH","2");
        if( myBtAdapter.isEnabled() ) {
            Log.i("HUH","3");
            if( myBtAdapter.isDiscovering() ) {
                Log.i("HUH","4");
                stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is currently " +
                        "in device discovery process." );
            } else {
                Log.i("HUH","5");
                stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is Enabled." );
                btnScanDevice.setEnabled( true );
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("HUH","6");
            stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is NOT enabled" );
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE );
            startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
        }
    }
}

private Button.OnClickListener btnScanDeviceOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View arg0 ) {

    }
};


@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    if( requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT ) {
        CheckBlueToothState();
    }
}

//In SDK15 (4.0.3) this method is now public as
//Bluetooth.fetchUuisWithSdp() and BluetoothDevice.getUuids()
public ParcelUuid[] servicesFromDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Class[] par = {};
        Method method = cl.getMethod("getUuids", par);
        Object[] args = {};
        ParcelUuid[] retval = (ParcelUuid[]) method.invoke(device, args);
        return retval;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals( action ) ) {
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra( BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE );
            btDevicesFound.add( btDevice );
            btArrayAdapter.add( btDevice.getName() + "\n" + btDevice.getAddress() );
            btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }           
    }
};
public static void startBluetooth(){
    try {
        myBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        myBtAdapter.enable();
    } catch ( NullPointerException ex ) {
        Log.e( "Bluetooth", "Device not available" );
    }
}

public static void stopBluetooth() {
    myBtAdapter.disable();
}
```

}

Here is the LogCat:

```
06-13 16:34:33.654: I/HUH(17008): 0
06-13 16:34:33.654: I/HUH(17008): 1
06-13 16:34:33.662: D/AndroidRuntime(17008): Shutting down VM
06-13 16:34:33.662: W/dalvikvm(17008): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.exercise.AndroidBluetooth/com.exercise.AndroidBluetooth.AndroidBluetooth}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at com.exercise.AndroidBluetooth.AndroidBluetooth.CheckBlueToothState(AndroidBluetooth.java:165)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at com.exercise.AndroidBluetooth.AndroidBluetooth.onCreate(AndroidBluetooth.java:124)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-13 16:34:33.662: E/AndroidRuntime(17008):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What line is 165?  (`CheckBlueToothState(AndroidBluetooth.java:165)`) ?

Comment: `stateBluetooth` seems to be `null`. Does `R.id.titleTvRight` exist in `R.layout.main`?

Comment: if R.id.titleTv does exist as Foern mentioned, try putting the rest of your onCreate() logic in onFinishInflate()

Comment: Floern you were right, thank you. What I had done was made a separate XML file trying to create a custom menu bar, which is where titleTvRight had been initialized.

Comment: Wish I could accept what you wrote as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish you had posted the whole class...  we don't know if you have cut out the cause or not...  for example, a possible reason;

Is `stateBluetooth` declared as a class variable or a local variable?  If you slipped.and created it int the onCreate, that could be why you get an NPE in the other method.

Answer (score 1):

Since the CheckBluetoothState () is the problem area and the stack trace is not giving much information, please try surrounding it with try catch and print the entire error. Also try debugging it by catching the exception at every single point. With the little info, that's all I could suggest. Update the question by posting the error from the catch block. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well the LogCat says NullPointerException, and its in line 165. This is the line    " stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT supported" );" within CheckBluetoothState

Answer (score 0):

***myBtAdapter = null;*** , I had the problem with this initialization

so change it to :

myBtAdapter = **BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter;**

Bingo!